# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente problema pero no se como solventarlo, haber si podeis ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano!

}[image: Error de NullPointerException que no consigo solventar]

[image: el xml][image: MainActivity]

Comment: Santa virgen, cuanta imagen donde debería haber texto. Por qué pones el código como imagen, cuando el código es claramente ***TEXTO***? Cuesta un montón intentar seguir tu pregunta así. De todas maneras, un NPE siempre será un NPE... estás llamando a `setOnClickListener()` sobre `btnMostrar`, que en realidad es `null` porque no se pudo encontrar en el layout actual, seguramente porque está en un fragment que no está cargado y por eso no existe en ese momento.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda y disculpas por el churro de imagen... justo es eso, lo que no se es como cargar antes el fragment, es decir tengo un layout principal que es donde va a buscar el boton "btnMostrar" y ahi no esta... esta en un fragment, como lo puedo cargar??

Comment: Si el botón está en el fragment... no sería normal que el fragment se encargase de gestionar su botón??

Comment: si seria lo suyo, podrias darme un ejemple de como se gestiona con un fragment los botones por favor?? muchas gracias!

Comment: Como podria usar el boton con los fragment?

Comment: @sintes para usarlo en el Fragment es lo mismo que realizaste en tu Activity pero asegura de definir en el layout que carga el Fragment el boton. Recuerda siempre agregar el codigo como texto no como imagen, saludos.

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822